# All bars/candles are getting painted

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

Working Version: Painted Bars/BarDimming

//@version=4 study("PaintedBars/BarDimming", overlay=true)

bar_color = bar_index < (bar_index[max(0, barstate.isrealtime ? bar_index - 1 : 0)] - 25) ? color.green : color.red

barcolor(color.green, -25)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
barcolor(color.green, -25)
```